# Build a c# project for use on a Mac

Tags: c#

I have a small program that I created in c# using Visual Studio and I am able to run it just fine on my windows, but I am wanting to give this to someone that is using a Mac.  How do I build this with a Mac in mind?  The project is with the WPF App (.NET Framework).

Comment: More details please. This is nothing to go off of.

Answer (score 0):

If you made a C# Windows app, you cannot run it on a Mac OS.  But if you made a C# console or asp.net core you can run it on Mac OS.  But you haven't given us much detail in your question to give you a definite yes or no.

Comment: The project is being built using the WPF App (.NET Framework) option.

Answer (score 0):

A WPF app cannot be run natively on a MAC OS system.  If you want your app to run as a Mac application in the MAC OS, WPF is simply the wrong technology to use.

A Mac may be able to run (any) windows program using Boot Camp (windows drivers for Apple Hardware) or Parallels (run windows in a virtual machine.)  This would be quite dependent on your user owning, installing, and configuring these tools.